# React state and conditional rendering

Tags: reactjs

I have a question about conditional rendering. I have a state (counter) in View1 and View2 components. I use the buttons to switch between the views. How do I prevent the counter from initializing to its original state when I switch between components. I need each component to have its own counter that does not return to its original state when I switch between View1 and View2.

https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-boyd-rbx3d

This is a small demo, i need use this for switching between two forms (withou losing values).

Answer (score 0):

You should define your counter state in parent of `view1` and `view2` and then pass counter value and function to update counter value in both components.

So your parent component will be like this:

```
export default function App() {
  const [view, setView] = React.useState(1);
  const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(1);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <button onClick={() => setView(1)}>View 1</button>
      <button onClick={() => setView(2)}>View 2</button>
      {
        {
          1: (
            <>
              <View1 key={1} setCounter={setCounter} counter={counter} />
            </>
          ),
          2: (
            <>
              <View2 key={2} setCounter={setCounter} counter={counter} />
            </>
          )
        }[view]
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Your child compoents will be like below:

View1.js

```
export default function View1(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      View111
      <button onClick={() => props.setCounter(props.counter + 1)}>Plus</button>
      {props.counter}
    </div>
  );
}
```

view2.js

```
export default function View2(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      View22222
      <button onClick={() => props.setCounter(props.counter + 1)}>Plus</button>
      {props.counter}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-bush-ixn8t)

Answer (score 0):

You need either to lift views state or to keep them mounted.

First variant with state lifting may look like that:

```js
import React, { useCallback } from "react";

function View({ label, counter, increment }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {label}
      <button onClick={increment}>Plus</button>
      {counter}
    </div>
  );
}

const labels = ["View111", "View222"];

export default function App() {
  const [view, setView] = React.useState(1);

  const [counters, setCounters] = React.useState([1, 1]);

  const increment = useCallback(() => {
    setCounters((v) => v.map((vv, idx) => (idx === view - 1 ? vv + 1 : vv)));
  }, [view]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <button onClick={() => setView(1)}>View 1</button>
      <button onClick={() => setView(2)}>View 2</button>
      <View
        counter={counters[view - 1]}
        increment={increment}
        label={labels[view - 1]}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Second variant with keeping views isolated may look like this:

```js
export default function App() {
  const [view, setView] = React.useState(1);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <button onClick={() => setView(1)}>View 1</button>
      <button onClick={() => setView(2)}>View 2</button>
      <div style={{ display: view === 1 ? undefined : "none" }}>
        <View1 key={1} />
      </div>
      <div style={{ display: view === 2 ? undefined : "none" }}>
        <View2 key={2} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```